# How do i retrieve the data from this xml page

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, response

So im trying to get all data to display back from the request but i cant get a response it just keeps giving me [object XMLDocument] or blank if i use .responseText

This is the request URL http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Chef&plot=full&r=xml

This is the site http://www.omdbapi.com/

This is the code i am using

```
<button onclick="loadXML()">Run</button>

<p id="output"></p>

<script>
function loadXML() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseXML;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Chef&plot=full&r=xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

All i need is a response returned and i can go from there but nothing i try is working :/

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for looking but i figured it out. I was receiving HTML tags and when i was outputting these tags they wouldnt show because they were echoing as HTML tags. The data was there just hidden. To resolve this i just saved the file instead, or it could be cleaned before outputting